# Why does POST request not work outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, post

I am running a springboot application and I ran it two ways:

1) running the spring boot app within eclipse `run as -> application` and selecting the Application.java for the spring boot app and running it in Eclipse itself. All the POST requests I am sending to it work perfectly fine.

2) compile the spring boot into a jar and then run it as `java -jar <>.jar`. The application starts fine but only SOME of the POST requests work this time.

Is there a reason why this could be happening? I am not sending the requests differently in either case. In the second case, I am getting a `500` error

Comment: How do you build your JAr archive? Is it a Maven project?

Comment: yes, it is a maven project.

Comment: Are you building it with Maven? `Run As > Maven build...` with goals `clean install`?

Comment: yes. I am running `clean install` and i even tried `clean install spring-boot:run`. Neither serve the request. The only way I can hit the endpoints is by running it as an Eclipse application (but only in certain cases), the rest of the POST requests work just fine....

Comment: Ok. Some logs would help I guess. Can you past your logs after an error 500?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured out the issue, I have an angular frontend where I am passing in Typescript objects back to the server which Spring then automatically maps to POJOs. For some reason, this mapping was working when I ran the application in Eclipse as an Eclipse application, but not when I ran the packaged JAR as a standalone server.

This is the reason behind the error, but if anyone can shed light on WHY this difference in mapping exists, it would make this less painful.